# Is it possible to upgrade from ios 4.3.5 to 5.0.1 even though the current version is 5.1?

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

My iphone has ios version 4.3.5 (8L1). I want to jailbreak/unlock it. I see that the latest jailbreak is for version 5.0.1 (by redsn0w). Itunes only allows me to upgrade to the latest version which is 5.1. But if I do that the jailbreak would be undoable.

Is there a way to upgrade to 5.0.1?

If not, is there a jailbreak available for 4.3.5?

Comment: Why are you trying to Jailbreak your phone?

Comment: You won't be able to unlock it unless it's a 3GS or you've been saving your baseband.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, you don't even have to hunt it to a Bittorent. You can just download it from the Apple servers by visiting the [RedMondPie](http://www.redmondpie.com/download-5.0.1-ios-for-iphone-4s-iphone-4-3gs-ipad-2-ipad-1-ipod-touch-final-direct-links/) website. Links are listed below the page.

Comment: Excellent find, did not know about that.  Cheers.

Comment: Very nice! But is it really official? I cannot make any sense of the domain http://appldnld.apple.com.

Comment: They claim to be official (`Here are the official download links to iOS 5.0.1:`). If it's really official, I don't know...

Comment: I don't believe Apple is still signing the iOS 5.0.1 IPSW anymore, so this wouldn't work unless you had your SHSH blobs for 5.0.1.

Comment: Yes, those are official IPSW download links - the URLs indicate that they're hosted on a subdomain of apple.com. If you want to restore an iPhone 4 (or earlier device) to iOS 5.0.1, you have to download the appropriate IPSW, stitch your SHSH blobs to the IPSW file, and use the result to restore your device. See [this guide](http://www.jailbreakqa.com/questions/32462/frequently-asked-questions#94647) for detailed instructions.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the download, it's possible, but as you don't you will likely have to hunt it down on Bittorrent, at which point you are in your own, but in essence you can apply any version you have got the file for *so long as you are upgrading, downgrading will not work*

The file was originally hosted [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1472) but the actual download link has been removed.  Apple only keep the most current versions available to download, so you will have to hunt a copy down and I am not able to assist in that (although if you know someone who has already used that level more than once then rifling through there Time Machine backups or iTunes folders may yield results.  Actually, as indicated in @michiel's answer, the links remain, they are just hard to find, so if you can find a list like the one maintained [here](http://www.redmondpie.com/download-5.0.1-ios-for-iphone-4s-iphone-4-3gs-ipad-2-ipad-1-ipod-touch-final-direct-links/) you are good to go.

To perform the upgrade once you have the file, and to stop iTunes simply checking for the most recent update and offering to apply that, you should select your iPhone in the connected device list after connecting by USB, go to the summary tab, check in the versions section.  Instead of just clicking update, hold the option key down and then click.  You will now be offered a finder style file picker to allow you to point it at your downloaded file.  Selecting this will allow you to upgrade to your choice of OS.

NOTE:  Perform a full backup of your phone before doing any upgrade.
NOTE: I am not able to explain why you cannot back level in the same manner, it's something to do with baseband and I don't understand why.

Comment: If you try to restore/upgrade/downgrade a device to an iOS version that Apple isn't signing right now (even if you have the right IPSW file), and you don't successfully replay the device's saved SHSH blobs (signature files) for that version, iTunes will deny the restore/upgrade/downgrade with an error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can just download the ipsw file for ios 5.0.1 (im sure you'd find it somewhere in google) and restore with pwned dfu mode on the latest redsn0w version 0.9.15b3

Comment: This looks like it has potential. However, we are looking for more in-depth answers. Would you mind editing your answer with more details on how to do this?